# AES-GCM issue with decrypting files in Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, cryptography, aes-gcm

I have a requirement in my project to download and store the files encrypted. After a research, I came to know AES with GCM meets my requirements. I made a demo application as a proof of concept. My code works fine when I try to encrypt and decrypt strings. I believe encryption is working because I'm getting a file with the same size as original file. The problem is when I decrypt the encrypted file, its shows exception as

> javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: error:1e000065:Cipher
>   functions:OPENSSL_internal:BAD_DECRYPT

Here is my code

encryption

```
    fun encrypt(data : ByteArray, iv : ByteArray, secretKey : SecretKey) : ByteArray{

    val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding")
    val parameterSpec = GCMParameterSpec(128, iv)
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, parameterSpec)
    val encrypted = cipher.doFinal(data)


    val byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(4 + iv.size + encrypted.size)
    byteBuffer.putInt(iv.size)
    byteBuffer.put(iv)
    byteBuffer.put(encrypted)
    val cipherMessage = byteBuffer.array()

    return cipherMessage
}
```

decryption

```
fun decrypt(cipherMessage : ByteArray, key : SecretKey) : ByteArray{

        val byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(cipherMessage)
        val ivLength = byteBuffer.int
        if (ivLength < 12 || ivLength >= 16) { 
            throw IllegalArgumentException("invalid iv length")
        }
        val iv = ByteArray(ivLength)
        byteBuffer.get(iv)
        val cipherText = ByteArray(byteBuffer.remaining())
        byteBuffer.get(cipherText)

        val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding")
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, GCMParameterSpec(128, iv))
        val plainText = cipher.doFinal(cipherText)
        return plainText
    }
```

Key generation

```
val secureRandom = SecureRandom()
        val key = ByteArray(16)
        secureRandom.nextBytes(key)
        val secretKey = SecretKeySpec(key, "AES")
        val iv = ByteArray(12) 
        secureRandom.nextBytes(iv)
```

and I'm using the following code to read and write file into disk, for the sake of simplicity I'm omitting irrelevant codes.

Read ,encrypt and write

```
do {
           count = input.read(data)
           if (count == -1)
               break

           total += count
           output.write(encrypt(data, iv, secretKey), 0, count)
        } while (true)
```

Read, Decrypt and write

```
do {
            count = input2.read(data)
            Log.e("Worker", "Count:$count")
            if (count == -1)
                break

            total += count
            output2.write(decrypt(data, secretKey), 0, count)
        } while (true)
```

Comment: _"I believe encryption is working because I'm getting a file with the same size as original file"_ How can they be the same size if the output file also contains the IV, the IV size, and the authentication tag?

Comment: @Michael: exactly, that's proof that it *isn't* working!

Comment: Where and how to you store the AES key after generation?